# Laravel 8. Routing issue. Always need to specifiy full path

Tags: routes, controller, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel.  I have created a few sample projects based on examples from the web.
I must have something setup incorrectly.

Whenever I create a route...
The examples always use a Relative PATH in the routes.
I am constantly forced to use a PRECISE PATHS in the routes.
Namespaces or BASEPATH is not working.
I want to just setup a BASEPATH in the beginning of all my projects but i feel like i would be circumventing a basic configuration issue....

The issue is not cache.

If i import a project using composer the relative routes work.
if i cut and paste example code into my project the relative routes fail everytime.

Composer or php artisan does something that every single tutorial fails to mention....
Any clues?   Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to set the correct `APP_URL` in the `.env` file to make sure `Laravel` resolves the paths correctly.

Posting an example code would help to recognize what could be the issue.